# How to add new font file to newly opened broser window

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular application that opens up a new browser and add HTML to that browser. In the newly opened browser, I want to use a custom font (a.ttf file). Is it possible?

```
openWindow(){
    let str = `<h3>Hello World</h3>`;
    let win = window.open("", "window", "width=100,height=100");
    win.document.body.innerHTML = str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **third party module** called [https://github.com/manuelmazzuola/angular-ui-router-styles.]
This is a simple module for AngularJS that provides the ability to have **route-specific CSS stylesheets**, by integrating with Angular **uiRouter**.

Example :

`.state('state1', {
        url: '/state1',
        controller: 'State1controller',
        template: '<div ui-view></div>',
        data: {
          css: [
            'styles/custom-state1.css',
            {
              name: 'layout',
              href: 'styles/state1-layout.css'
            }
          ]
        }
      })`

and specify fonts in css